# Variable width table with automated line break in multicols environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicol, cases

I am creating a cheat-sheet using the `multicols` environment. Inside `multicols` I want to variate some statements via cases: In the statement, I want to add in-line rows (just like the `cases` environment does) with the options to choose from for the next part of the statement.

I tried the `tabular` environment, but there are no automated line breaks.
I tried the `tabularx` environment, but due to the fixed width, the table does not blend in well used in-line (especially when there is not enough text to fill the line).

So, is there a way to create variable-width tables with maximum-width settable to the `multicols` columnwidth and automated line-breaks?

[image]

Comment: Clear as mud... can you provide a visual image of what you're after?

Comment: Sorry. [I tried.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMqSg.png) Thanks again.

Comment: I have revised my answer a bit, to remedy some `\vspace` deficiencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not fool-proof.  It cannot page break (of course, neither can the `tabular` approach of the OP).  Also, there are additional nefarious possibilities, in that the placement of the final brace is governed by whether the top text or bottom text is longest as set in an `\hbox`, which does not account for the fact that flush-alignment of the actual `\parbox` could conceivably reverse that conclusion, undetected.

Finally, the `...` must be manually added on blank lines, using `\\...\\...` etc.

EDITED to use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`, so as to work properly in a `multicols` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,tabto,multicol}
\newlength\parboxdepth
\newcommand\variate[2]{\bgroup%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{#2}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\wd2\relax%
    \let\endbraceB\relax%
  \else%
    \let\endbraceT\relax%
  \fi
  $\Bigl\{$\tabto*{0pt}\edef\myindent{\TabPrevPos}\renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\baselineskip=2\baselineskip\relax%
      \tabto{\myindent}#2\endbraceB}}%
    \setbox2=\hbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\baselineskip=2\baselineskip\relax%
      \tabto{\myindent}#1\endbraceT}}%
    \ifdim\dp2>\dp0\relax\parboxdepth=\dp2\relax\else\parboxdepth=\dp0\relax\fi%
  \raisebox{-.5\dimexpr\Lstackgap\relax}{\stackon{\copy0}{\copy2}}%
  \ifdim\parboxdepth>\baselineskip\relax\vspace{-.66\baselineskip}\else%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}\fi\vspace{-\parskip}%
  \par%
  \leavevmode\tabto{\myfinalindent}%
  \rule[-\baselineskip]{0pt}{2\baselineskip}%
\egroup}
\def\endbraceT{\raisebox{-.25\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{$\Bigr\}$}%
  \tabto*{0pt}\xdef\myfinalindent{\TabPrevPos}}
\def\endbraceB{\raisebox{+.25\dimexpr\Lstackgap}{$\Bigr\}$}%
  \tabto*{0pt}\xdef\myfinalindent{\TabPrevPos}}
%\textwidth 3.5in\relax% FOR NON-MULTICOLS TEST
\setstackgap{L}{.8\baselineskip}% \variate BASELINE SKIP; CAN BE VARIED TO SUIT
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Depending on \variate{Thing A}{Thing B} I want to end my statement on
  \variate{Conclusion C}{Conclusion D}. 
Using \variate{tabular}{tabularx} gives me \variate{no line breaks for
  statements exceeding the multicols column-width}{automated line-breaks\\...}
  but \variate{enables variable column-width.\\...}{uses whole column width
  for short statements.}
All in all, \variate{I want my cases to start in line, break like this at the
  end of the multicols-column and end at a variable length in-line}{...\\...
  \\...}.
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

In a `multicols` environment, there can still be an issue if the column break occurs in the middle of a `\variate` argument, as seen here:

[image]

With `multicols` commented out, and `\textwidth` set to 3.5in.

[image]

Comment: First, thanks alot for your answer. Just had more time to work with it. I have some problems in `multicols`. The linebreak is dependent from "\textwidth 3.5in\relax", is it not? It seems to not be compatible with use of columns as it results in their widths being off. If I do not use `multicols`, but try to set the columns via the textwidth command, I do not get any column but the first, and it does not pagebreak correctly.

Comment: @Ramen Pagebreaks certainly will not work, as mentioned in my answer.  Let me think about the multi-columns a bit more.

Comment: @Ramen Please see my edit.